# Remove Nested HTML Comment String using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string of nested html comment level look like this structure `<!-- some text <!-- some text --> -->` . I want to remove out every comment tag that is inside another comment, so that the final result is `<!-- some text some text -->` .

This is a regx pattern that I used but it does not match the string comment like I want

```js
<!--[\S\s]+?(<!--[\S\s]+?-->)[\S\s]+?-->
```

which is used to match this string pattern:

```
<!-- {% set Navbar = request.Navbar if request.Navbar else "True" %} -->
<!-- {% if Navbar == "True" %}
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <form method="GET" id="frm" name="frm" role="form">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div style="margin-top: 8px;">
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <input name="From" id="From" value="L___ From R___" class="form-control" placeholder="Effective From *" style="width: 100%;" required data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <input name="To" id="To" value="L___ To R___" class="form-control" placeholder="Effective To *" style="width: 100%;" required data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <select name="Active" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                        <!-- {% if Active == 'Y' %}
                            <option selected value="Y">Active (Yes)</option>
                            <option value="N">Active (No)</option>
                        {% else %}
                            <option value="Y">Active (Yes)</option>
                            <option selected value="N">Active (No)</option>
                        {% endif %} -->
                    </select>
                </div>

                <!-- {% set CurrencyList = getRecord('MKT_CURRENCY') %} -->
                <!-- {% if len(CurrencyList) > 0 %}
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-left: 0;">
                        <select name="FilterCurrency" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                        <!-- {% for CurrObj in CurrencyList %}
                            <option L___'selected' if FilterCurrency == CurrObj.ID else ''R___  value="L___ CurrObj.ID R___">L___ CurrObj.ID R___</option>
                        {% endfor %} -->
                        </select>
                    </div>
                {% endif %} -->
                <label class="col-sm-1" style="padding:0px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-labeled btn-primary" style="padding: 7px 25px;">
                        Show
                    </button>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 8px;">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a id="print" onclick="" class="btn btn-flat btn-labeled btn-success">
                    <span class="btn-label icon fa fa-print"></span> Print
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endif %} -->
```

And the result after removing nested comment should be:

```js
<!-- {% set Navbar = request.Navbar if request.Navbar else "True" %} -->
<!-- {% if Navbar == "True" %}
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <form method="GET" id="frm" name="frm" role="form">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div style="margin-top: 8px;">
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <input name="From" id="From" value="L___ From R___" class="form-control" placeholder="Effective From *" style="width: 100%;" required data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <input name="To" id="To" value="L___ To R___" class="form-control" placeholder="Effective To *" style="width: 100%;" required data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <select name="Active" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                        {% if Active == 'Y' %}
                            <option selected value="Y">Active (Yes)</option>
                            <option value="N">Active (No)</option>
                        {% else %}
                            <option value="Y">Active (Yes)</option>
                            <option selected value="N">Active (No)</option>
                        {% endif %}
                    </select>
                </div>

                {% set CurrencyList = getRecord('MKT_CURRENCY') %}
                {% if len(CurrencyList) > 0 %}
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-left: 0;">
                        <select name="FilterCurrency" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                        {% for CurrObj in CurrencyList %}
                            <option L___'selected' if FilterCurrency == CurrObj.ID else ''R___  value="L___ CurrObj.ID R___">L___ CurrObj.ID R___</option>
                        {% endfor %} 
                        </select>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <label class="col-sm-1" style="padding:0px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-labeled btn-primary" style="padding: 7px 25px;">
                        Show
                    </button>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 8px;">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a id="print" onclick="" class="btn btn-flat btn-labeled btn-success">
                    <span class="btn-label icon fa fa-print"></span> Print
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endif %} -->
```

This what I tried on [regx101](https://regex101.com/r/pLiGMS/4).

Please kindly help me to remove any nested html comment from string above. Thank you.

Comment: so , you want a Python regex?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I am using javacript regex.

Comment: not in that link you aint

Comment: @JaromandaX, sorry I have updated the regx101 link to use javascript. Thanks

Comment: Can you reference (link) to the HTML/XML/SGML spec that says that _Nested Comments_ exist ? As far as I know, the W3C spec has always defined comments as the first closure: `<!--[\s\S]*?-->` similar for CDATA

Comment: Did you just manually place comments around a block of pre-made html ? So now you have invalid html because of it ? You'll need to fix it using recursive constructs in code since JS regex is not equipped.

Comment: @sln, first of all, apologize for late reply. yes it is not a valid html actually. This string was generated by templating engine jinja2 and I run js script to pass by any jinja2 syntax just to toggle them showing/hiding in the template. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there's an elegant solution with regex:

```
// "template" contains the original string

let parts = template.split(/(<!--|-->)/);

let result = '';
let state = 0;

for (const part of parts) {
    switch(part) {
        case '<!--': 
            if (state === 0) {
                result += part;
            }
            state++;
            break;
            
        case '-->':
            if (state === 1) {
                result += part;
            }
            state--;
            break;
            
        default:
            result += part;
    }
}            
        
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting. How does the before / after text look ?

Comment: @sln: exactly like in the question. (except for leading and trailing spaces but I ignored them).

Comment: @sln: example: https://onecompiler.com/nodejs/3zr3g25pc

Comment: Yeah this does what he wants to do. Nice!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, thank you very much. it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a Perl 1 liner in case you just need something that can be a stand alone
file/directory processor if its needed.

I know it can't be done in JS regex. This is one alternative.
To be clear you're removing the inner html Comment syntax  `<!--` and `-->` only.
Not the comment!

This is actually a perilous thing to do since any syntax can be embedded in quotes
anywhere.

A regex or other method is needed to get the balanced text comment as a whole
then proceed to remove just the inner syntax in a callback.

Engines that can do that are the big three Perl, Pcre (Php) and C#, and probably  others are available that do recursion.

This Perl 1 liner can be fed files an do them all in a single shot.
Again sorry for no strict JS answer here, but these can be alternatives.

To test it out:  http://tpcg.io/_U6E4OE

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = "";

my $html = <DATA>;

sub Replace { ($_) = @_; s/<!--|-->//g; return $_; }
$html =~ s/(?s)<!--((?:(?!<!--|-->).)*(?:<!--(?1)-->(?:(?!<!--|-->).)*)*)-->/ "<!--".Replace($1)."-->" /eg;
print $html, "\n\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I not using perl, however the result script is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your problem statement could be described as removing the inner HTML comments only, you could use the following regex, which uses a tempered dot trick:

```
Find:    <!--(?:(?!<!--).)*?-->
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

Explanation:

- `<!--` match leading `<!--`
- `(?:(?!<!--).)*?` match any content WITHOUT crossing another `<!--`
- `-->` then match the nearest closing `-->`

Comment: Thank you, I modified your regx pattern one step further to match every <!-- --> inside another <!-- -->. The pattern is `<!--(?:(?!<!--).)*?\D*-->` but still not every <!-- --> inside another <!-- --> get matched. here it is https://regex101.com/r/FFsiez/1

Comment: Could you please help me to match every comment statement inside <!-- --> ? I want to replace <!-- and --> with "" for those nested. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible using plain JavaScript regexp functionality, and I think Tim Biegeleisen's answer already comes as close as it gets, though it'll  remove *any* markup comment not just those "nested" ones. For a regexp to target only nested ones, and moreover to only target the comment delimiters rather than the entire comment, functionality such as provided by traditional Unix `sed` (or `ed`/`vi`) would be required, allowing you to match a regexp within a larger regexp match.

Btw. your "nested" commenting syntax is invalid in HTML according to [The WHATWG HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#comments) chapter 13.1.6 paragraph 2:

> Optionally, text, with the additional restriction that the text must not start with the string ">", nor start with the string "->", nor contain the strings "", or "--!>", nor end with the string "<!-".

And is also invalid in SGML where pairs of `--` sequences delimit comments in any markup declaration (XML and HTML comments being just a special case):

```
<!ENTITY bla "some text"
    -- an SGML comment --
    -- another comment -->
```

Noting this so that you can accept to bite the bullet and change those "nested comments" manually in a text editor, because this "nested comment" phenomenon won't show ever again and thus doesn't seem to warrant programming a solution ;)